# Protect excel sheet but allow data entry with form

Tags: excel

I have an excel form that input data, but i dont want the users to be able to play with the data once added to the sheet. I just want them to be able to add data with the form. Thing is, if I protect my sheet, I wont be able to add data via the form.

I can unlock the first row, making it possible to add data, and lock the rest of the sheet. But that only fix 90% of my problem.

I tried this code in ThisWorkbook :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Me.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Then I locked my sheet and it's still fiving me error 1004.

Comment: Protect using `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`.

Comment: I paste that in `ThisWorkbook` ? @BigBen

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Protection.aspx You do it in the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: I read the "UserInterfaceOnly Option". I Copied the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` in `Workbook_Open event`. THEN, I protected the sheet. But It still gives me error 1004.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you tried, thanks.

Comment: Just did. Thank youi @BigBen

Comment: I'm guessing you need to specify more parameters of `Protect`.

Comment: nvm. It's working. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Me.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

And then lock your sheet like you normally would.

IF you want to read more on the subject : cpearson.com/excel/Protection.aspx

Thank you @BigBen